# calculating standard deviation with a previous calculation and a delta

Tags: standard-deviation

I have a large amount of data for which I have got a system that has calculated the standard deviation.

I can augment this data when doing the calculation. Such as also calculating the mean and count and store them for later use. The dataset is large enough for me not to want to recalculate (loading into memory will take more than ten min).

Let's say I got 4 million records

Once every day I will get an additional 10.000 records. How would I go about reusing what I know about the 4mio records and calculate the standard deviation of the 4.01mio records

Since I'm going to be doing similar calculations for other stats I'd gladly here of ressource to go read as well

Comment: This is a duplicate (many times over). 1. Do you want the standard deviation that's the square root of the Bessel-corrected variance or of the n-denominator variance? 2. Do you already have the sd of the set of new records or are you taking these in one at a time and updating the sd with each?

Comment: @Glen_b yeah I thought it might be and that I just simply lacked the vocabulary to search for. So my searched ended up empty. If you know of a few of the duplicates. I would like if this was marked as a duplicate! 1) probably the n-dnominated (since I don't know what the other is) 2) I have the complete set of data and can easily calculate the st if that's the easiest approach

Comment: [Bessel's correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_correction) is the use of the $n-1$ denominator in sample variance -- this is the usual formula for sample variance. 2. It's not a matter of what's easiest, it's what you want. I'll assume you are happy to just add the new observations one at a time.

Comment: @glen_b it was more of a "both works for me" statement :) and thanks for the explanation